# Ubuntu Mate theme has no "Traditional" option after update to Jammy

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, panel

I updated my computer, and now the theme is all screwed up. The panel applets in Mate don't work, the icons are wrong or missing. In Mate-Tweak, the option I would usually choose, "Traditional" is missing. The selections are Gnome, and open suse. I tried searching for missing, libraries, and packages, but nothing makes my desktop look proper.

how to I return to my regular panel appearance?

Comment: My 22.04 Ubuntu MATE system offers Traditional as a choice. Perhaps something went wrong with your upgrade. https://i.imgur.com/vv5g38B.png

Comment: yeah, I reckon. They messed with my seat settings, everything still works, but i hate how it looks.

Comment: I don't care for the choice of icons either in 22.04. This was a test install for me, and I decided to stick with 20.04 after seeing what it looked like.

Comment: I'm slowly addapting it, I havent found the traditional panel option yet, but the theme I had was called ambient-mate, I grabbed it off my other computer, and used the appearance app to install it. least I have that back. Its not that this PC is critical, its the one I use at my local makerspace, for tinkering on various things. its just annoying. I had that panel set up the way i wanted it. grrrr